# Recyclerview: Decelerate to targetview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using Recyclerview with LinearSnapHelper to implement a scrollable timepicker. I want the recyclerview to fling fast in the beginning and decelerate at the end. Samsung alarm clock and other device alarm clock has this kind of behaviour. Please check the image gif added below.
[image]

[image]

```
override fun attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?) {
       println("attachToRecyclerView")
       scroller = Scroller(recyclerView?.context, DecelerateInterpolator())
       super.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}
    

override fun calculateScrollDistance(velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): IntArray {
       val out = IntArray(2)
       scroller?.fling(0, 0, velocityX, velocityY, -1500, 1500, -1500, 1500)
       out[0] = scroller?.finalX ?: 0
       out[1] = scroller?.finalY ?: 0
       return out
}
```

overriding calculateScrollDistance resulted in decrease in scroll speed uniformly.

overriding attachToRecyclerView resulted nothing.

Help me achieve the same behaviour as shown in the reference.

What I have achieved so far.

[image: What I have achieved]

Comment: post some code what you've achieved, what you've tried, what isn`t working as exepected... without code all is just guessing...

Comment: @snachmsm I have added reference image of the alarm clock I want to achieve and the code i've tried.

Comment: I didn't see your app's gif for better reference but I think you can try decreasing the velocity value to achieve less sensitivity so the scrolling stops more quickly.

Comment: Decrease by 2 times for example:
`scroller?.fling(0, 0, velocityX / 2, velocityY / 2, -1500, 1500, -1500, 1500)`

Comment: @TamHuynh It does reduces the velocity value, and scrolling stops more quickly. I dont want to stop the scrolling quickly, instead I want to scroll fast at the beginning and scroll slowly to reach the targetview. Please see the gif to understand the requirement clearly.

Comment: Then try custom the factor of `DecelerateInterpolator` constructor, pass different float value to `DecelerateInterpolator(1.5f), or lower than 1 to see if it fits your need

Comment: @TamHuynh tried that already. nothing changed.